# Float right moves under float left element when height changes

Tags: html, css

I have three elements which each have a float property. The first element has some content and is floated left. The sidebar and a secondary element are floated right. When the height of the second element (blue in the codepen) changes, the third (green) element eventually moves partially underneath the first element.

What am I missing to keep the third (green) element in the same position as the blue element, without shifting positions?

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MMxGgN)

```css
  .test {
    background: purple;
    max-width: 967px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 60px 0;
  }

  .one {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    background: beige;
    float: left;
  }

  .two {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background: blue;
    float: right;
  }

  .three {
    background: green;
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    float: right;
  }
```

```html
  <section class="test">
    <article class="one"></article>
    <aside class="two"></aside>
    <section class="three"></section>
  </section>
```

Here is the best illustration i can come up with. Note how the third section stays on the right, even when the secondary element is at least as high as the first:

```
-------   -----
|     |   |   |
|_____|   |___|
          _____
          |   |
          |___|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply clear the float in the third element using `clear:right;`

```css
.test {
  background: purple;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.one {
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  background: beige;
  float: left;
}

.two {
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  float: right;
}

.three {
  background: green;
  height: 50px;
  width: 80px;
  float: right;
  clear:right;
}
```

```html
<section class="test">
  <article class="one"></article>
  <aside class="two"></aside>
  <section class="three"></section>
</section>
```

Comment: I accepted this as the answer, thank you. Do you have any helpful resource to explain why this works?

Comment: @Hewe I don't really have any specific ressource but all you have to know is how `clear` works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what you are looking for ?  Wrapped the blue and green in a div, floated that, and removed the floats from the blue and green.  Changing the height of the blue keeps them stacked vertically, although they still wrap under the 1st element when you narrow the window.  Do you want the blue and green still aligned at the top and them just overlapping the first element ?

```css
.test {
  background: purple;
  max-width: 967px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 60px 0;
  position:relative;
}

.one {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: beige;
  float: left;
}

.two {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background: blue;

}

.three {
  background: green;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;

}
#wrap {
    float: right;
  }
```

```html
<section class="test">
  <article class="one"></article>
  <div id="wrap">
  <aside class="two"></aside>
  <section class="three"></section>
  </div>
</section>
```

You could absolutely position that wrapper also.  Not clear on what you want.

```
#wrap {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    padding:60px 0px 0px 0px;
  }
```

Comment: What i am looking for is stated in the post: keep the third (green) element in the same position as the blue element, without shifting positions. Let me add that I cannot wrap the two divs into one, they have to stay separated.